# Operator Associativity Test vs Operand Evaluation Order

Tags: operators, logical-operators

I am trying to write a simple code structure that verifies whether the `&&` operator in a language (not a specific language, so I can't get help of truthy/falsy values) is left-associative or right-associative.

My first shot was to define functions that print their names, for example, and return some boolean values, and then call them like `p() && q() && r()`. I thought that if I see `r` before `p` and `q` in the output, then the operator is right-associative. However, I noticed that this gives me no answer. It just gives a clue of the operand evaluation order, I think. Consider the following python script:

```
def p():
    print("p")
    return 3

def q():
    print("q")
    return 4

def r():
    print("r")
    return 2

print(p() ** q() ** r())
```

The output of the code is

```
p
q
r
43046721
```

By the help of the numbers, we can deduce that the operator is right-associative in this case, but we also see that its operand evaluation order is left-to-right. So, I saw that the associativity doesn't exactly imply operand evaluation order (in this case, at least). So, seeing `p` before the others actually doesn't say anything about the associativity of the operator. (I don't know whether "This doesn't imply anything about the associativity" claim is valid with boolean operators as well.)

We can see what is what in this case from the output with the help of the integers, but I couldn't find a way with using booleans, as there are only true and false. Maybe there is a completely different way.

Comment: In many languages your approach with functions should work, because `&&` is short-circuiting (so `p() && q() && r()` will print only `p` if `p` returns false in c++). This will prove that `&&` is sort of left-associative. If you're interested in languages where `&&` does not short-circuit, mention the language. This is likely not answerable for arbitrary lang in general without some narrowing restrictions.

Comment: In python you can override magics (`__bool__` for `and` and `or`, since those interpret in boolean context, and `__or__`/`__and__`/`__xor__` for `|`/`&`/`^`, resp.) to also print something, it should reveal order of operations. `__bool__` will be called when the corresponding object is interpreted as boolean (`a and b` calls `a.__bool__()` and then `b.__bool__()`, if you don't take containers with `__len__` into account).

Comment: @STerliakov a similar question to what I had in this problem: does short circuit evaluation imply the operand evaluation order or the associativity?

Comment: Short circuit evaluation implies both: you have guarantee (in languages where it is so, of course) that right operand will **never** be evaluated if left is sufficient to deduce the operation result. It is pretty powerful feature, and it definitely implies that evaluation goes from let to right and also implies left associativity (since you have to start with leftmost two operands first).

Comment: @STerliakov Umm, I didn't get it. I think short circuiting clearly implies that the operand evaluation order is left-to-right, but I can't say the same with associativity. I can define a grammar that evaluates `a && b && c` as `a && (b && c)` and stops evaluating when it evaluates `a` as `false`. Same with the left-associatives. If you evaluate `a && b && c` as `(a && b) && c`, you stop evaluating `a && b` and say it's false, and then you are left with `false && c`, which again short-circuits to `false`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry, my claim doesn't follow. If `&&` is not overridable, `&&` can be applied in any order, it does not affect the (boolean) result or side effects. In [c++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), associativity is defined in standard clearly, there is simlar page for C. In python, all operators except `**` are left-associative, it's again mandated by standard. You can overload `operator&&` in c++ to add print there and see the applications order, but beware that it won't short-circuit - only default `&&` does.